# Creating sample function skeleton from complex typescript function prototype

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, ngrx

The following is a function signature from a [NgRx library](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/store/src/selector.ts).

```
export interface MemoizedSelector<
  State,
  Result,
  ProjectorFn = DefaultProjectorFn<Result>
> extends Selector<State, Result> {
  release(): void;
  projector: ProjectorFn;
  setResult: (result?: Result) => void;
  clearResult: () => void;
}
```

I want to create a function that matches with the above signature `MemoizedSelector`. I can create one with many trials and error method. The problem that I face is that I have to refer many other function signature (eg. `DefaultProjectorFn`) being used in the above function to match that I create.

I'm new to functional programming. Is there a tool or tips that I can use when creating typescript functions for complex functions like above?

Comment: Do you want to declare a function that takes a selector as a *parameter*?

Comment: I want to declare a ```selector```, and force other selectors to follow the signature. I have a few ```derived components``` in Angular which has a ```base component```. I want all the ```derived components``` to have selectors that follow the signature of the selector in the ```base class```.